# In how many ways can five different sweets be split amongst two people if each person must have at least one sweet?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can five different sweets be split amongst two people if each person must have at least one sweet?

I tried $5 C 1 + 5 C 2 + 5 C 3 + 5 C 4 = 30$, however, the answer is $20$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also arrived at the answer of 30. There are $2^5$ ways to split different sweets between two people, only two of them do not satisfy the "each person must have at least one sweet" condition.

Comment: I also agree with $30$, because $\sum_0^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$ therefore if we take out the "last" two, i.e. $\binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{n}$ (the two cases where each person receives _all_ of the sweets) then we get $2^n - 2$ which in this case is $2^5 - 1 - 1 = 32 - 2 = 30$.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with your answer of $30$...

Unless there is some other condition, such as one person gets $3$ sweets and the other person gets $2$ sweets--which would give an answer of $20$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to "set you at ease" with your answer, this is a case where it's small enough that we *can* enumerate all possible instances.  Let's assume that the sweets are labeled a, b, c, d, and e.  One possible situation could be $\{a, bcde\}$...we can enumerate all possible cases:

1. $\{a, bcde\}$
2. $\{b, acde\}$
3. $\{c, abde\}$
4. $\{d, abce\}$
5. $\{e, abcd\}$
6. $\{ab, cde\}$
7. $\{ac, cde\}$
8. $\{ad, bce\}$
9. $\{ae, bcd\}$
10. $\{bc, ade\}$
11. $\{bd, ace\}$
12. $\{be, acd\}$
13. $\{cd, abe\}$
14. $\{ce, abd\}$
15. $\{de, abc\}$
16. $\{abc, de\}$
17. $\{abd, ce\}$
18. $\{abe, cd\}$
19. $\{acd, be\}$
20. $\{ace, bd\}$
21. $\{ade, bc\}$
22. $\{bcd, ae\}$
23. $\{bce, ad\}$
24. $\{bde, ac\}$
25. $\{cde, ab\}$
26. $\{abcd, e\}$
27. $\{abce, d\}$
28. $\{abde, c\}$
29. $\{acde, b\}$
30. $\{bcde, a\}$